# how to create my android chat room Server on C#?

Tags: c#, android, chat

I'm working on Chat room for Android . Know I want to know if it's possible to instead of create my server as android app , create it as a C# app ? if yes , is there any special thing that i should consider to create my client's and Server , or I can create them without considering that the clients are android app and the server is C# app ?
thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to play with chat you should use XMPP. A free XMPP server is openfire and is very good.

Comment: Generally try to go that way. Is the most common.

Comment: can you link some  tutorial .

Comment: Google xmpp and c# and you will find many. Openfire runs very well also with java.

Comment: There also projects in codeproject.